# How to use project fields in valueexpressions in WorkFront task report

Tags: attask, workfront-api

I'm trying to create a new task report in WorkFront and I need to use project-level fields in a valueexpression, but the system doesn't seem to recognize anything I try to use off the project object.  I know the field is accessible because I can simply use valuefield and it can display the field just fine.  I am assuming there's some difference in syntax when chaining objects I'm not aware of?

Example valueexpression using the task's referenceNumber that works just fine:

```
valueexpression=IF({referenceNumber}=="1234","Y","N")
```

Example using the project's referenceNumber that does **not** work:

```
valueexpression=IF({project:referenceNumber}=="1234","Y","N")
```

I'm obviously missing something...  but what really confuses me is I can instead just use valuefield with the same syntax and this works fine:

```
valuefield=project:referenceNumber
```

What am I missing?

Thanks-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an embarrassing amount of trial and error, I finally found the correct syntax to be:

```
valueexpression=IF({project}.{referenceNumber}=="1234","Y","N")
```